# How to join two datasource which return all rows and group by condition?

Tags: linq, join

I have a problem when using LINQ to join two datasource. Two datasource created by a query like :

var A = (from....
         group .... into grp
         select new
         {
            Qty = grp.Count(),
            Code = grp.Key.Code,
            Name = grp.Key.Name
         });

var B = (from....
         group .... into grp
         select new
         {
            Qty = grp.Count(),
            Code = grp.Key.ContCode,
            Name = grp.Key.ContName
         });

Value of 'A' will be returned like this :

```
    Qty-Code-Name

    1-10A-Cont10
    1-20B-Cont20
    1-30C-Cont30
```

Value of 'B' will be returned like this :

```
    Qty-Code-Name

    1-10A-Cont10
    1-20B-Cont20
    1-30C-Cont30
    1-40D-Cont40
    1-50E-Cont50
```

I want to join A and B (or do somethings) and the result like this (which sum column 'Qty' if they have the same 'Code' and 'Name') :

```
    Qty-Code-Name

    2-10A-Cont10
    2-20B-Cont20
    2-30C-Cont30
    1-40D-Cont40
    1-50E-Cont50
```

How can I do it ? Please help me.
Thank you very much !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concat the two datasources and than group by `code` and `name`.
Something like:

```
var q = from v in A.Concat(B)
        group v by new {v.Code,v.Name } into g
        select new
        {
            Qty = g.Sum(a => a.Qty),
            CodeName = g.Key.Code,
            Name = g.Key.Name
         };
```

Comment: Thanks, it works ! Actually, I've tried 'Concat' method before but get an error. Now I try it again and found my problem. It's beacause 'Qty' field in both datasource are not the same type, so I cant 'concat' them. [In my question above, 'Qty=grp.Count()' have the same type of 'Int']                                                              Thanks again !